# MySQL GRANT NDB_STORED_USER all users

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grant MySQL GRANT NDB_STORED to all users - this is the command to the single user

GRANT NDB_STORED_USER ON *.* TO 'wp_gmvgw'@'%';

I have tried different things but getting "ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT"

what i think i need is a script to list users and run the command to each user.

Any help would be amazing.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: [NDB_STORED_USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_ndb-stored-user) This privilege is available only if the NDB storage engine is enabled, do you have it enabled ?